# Madeline proto upload image

Tags: php, telegram, proto

I am trying to upload an image with MadelineProto on Telegram and found an example code to do that.  The issue is that I want to use a variable to store the image path and then use that variable in the code, but the code seems to only accept a string value.

`'file' => 'variable goes here'`

**Code:**

```
 $sentMessage = yield $MadelineProto->messages->sendMedia([
    'peer' => '@channel',
    'media' => [
        '_' => 'inputMediaUploadedPhoto',
        'file' =>'image.jpg'
    ],
    'message' => 'this is a test massage',
    'parse_mode' => 'Markdown'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this do the job.

```
$filePath = 'long/path/to/file.ext'
$sentMessage = yield $MadelineProto->messages->sendMedia([
    'peer' => '@channel',
    'media' => [
        '_' => 'inputMediaUploadedPhoto',
        'file' => $filePath
    ],
    'message' => 'this is a test massage',
    'parse_mode' => 'Markdown'
]);
```